# What is the max ethereum allowed in a private network for the whole network?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, c#

When I build a private chain setup, what is the maximum Geth ethereum I can have for the life of the network.  Another way of asking the question would be: What is the maximum ethereum one account can have?  What is the maximum ethereum all accounts collectively can have? On the same note, what is the maximum number of blocks I can have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question! Let's look at each question in particular:

**Max number of blocks**

Theoretically there should be no upper limit since the chain of blocks must be able to continually grow over time. However, since the block number is stored as a finite integer, there is a limit to how high this number can be. See the full discussion in [this related question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26942/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-blocks-in-a-blockchain).

**Max number of ETH**

I ran a little experiment using `ganache-cli` locally, which is a good proxy for `geth` since it is governed by the same rules of the game. See what was allowed by `ganache`:

```
ganache-cli --defaultBalanceEther 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And it can go on like this for a long time. You can query the balance of the accounts with web3 for example:

```
> web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0])
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 619, c: [ 1000 ] }
```

BigNumber can [get you a long way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979783/understanding-the-limitations-of-the-bignumber-js-library). But I'm curious to know what the Ethereum protocol itself specifies for maximum balance / transaction amount.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested with parity ethereum client 2.5.10: maximum possible value was

```
0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

being 64 hexadecimal signs -> 256 bit long. Anything exceeding it leads to a [node panic](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/11268)